# Can Python with turtle and tkinter replace NetLogo? Which is worth more the time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I never went too far into NetLogo, and being a novice in Python I started looking into the turtle module, aiming towards ABM. I have seen some simple implementations of the turtle module (turtledemo and YouTube) but none were comparable to NetLogo library's examples. I went over (once) the [mesa tutorials](http://mesa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) and it seemed interesting but, as it says, more advanced stuff require Javascript. I've also read that NetLogo is fast to pick up.

Considering the above, and adding your own experience, could NetLogo be a better choice than Python? Could you estimate how hard each path would be? Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I teach ABM. I used to use Python for my course,
using a module that provides some NetLogo-like functionality:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alan-isaac/econpy/master/abm/gridworld/gridworld.py

I gave that up.  Although Python is a great language for
teaching programming, NetLogo is a much better language for
teaching ABM.  (Both started out as teaching languages,
very roughly speaking, and became much more.)  It is very
easy to get started with NetLogo.  It's builtin facilities
also support very sophisticated model building.  These facilities
can be extended when needed.

Comment: Python did not start as a teaching language. You must be confusing it with Pascal.

Comment: @DYZ Python grew out of ABC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_(programming_language)

Comment: So what? Unlike ABC, it was not meant to be a teaching language.

Comment: @DXY You seem to be overlooking "started out as, *very roughly speaking*". That points to ABC, since Python is typically considered its successor language and Guido worked on ABC and was influenced by that work. But feel free to worry about this.